# Jenkins && Gihub webhook - Illegal number of parameter values

Tags: github, jenkins, webhooks

I'm trying to run a build using Github's Webhook for job with parameter (*branch=master*).

From Github - I see 500 err, and message in Jenkin's log:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal number of parameter values for branch: 2

Call looks like:

http://user:pass@jenkins.domain.tld:8080/job/PipelineBuild/buildWithParameters?token=triggerPipelieBuild&branch=master

If run it using `curl` - same error appears, but build triggers.

Build have one parameter with one value.
URL have same - `branch=master`.

What's wrong here (or - what I'm doing wrong here)?

Why "values for branch: 2" - if there is only one value - "master"?

I see it's explicitly error from [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/SimpleParameterDefinition.java#L33), but why?

`buildWithParameters` count both *token=triggerPipelieBuild* and *branch=master* as two params?

But error says:

> "number of parameter values for **branch**: 2"

Also - that worked yesterday. Same requests.

Comment: Check the webhook configuration on GitHub to see which URL is actually being called. I believe that GitHub, possibly depending on the configuration, sends extra query parameters, such as the affected branch and SHA.

Comment: Thanks, @ChristopherOrr. I checked it and only one a bit weird thig is the *Request URL* in the _Recent Deliveries_. If in my webhook's settings I set `buildWithParameters?token=triggerPipelieBuild&foo=master` - in  _Recent Deliveries_ it is vice versa - `buildWithParameters?foo=master&token=triggerPipelieBuild`. But not sure it could be a cause for my issue.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue, but it's interesting to see that in recent deliveries, GitHub isn't adding a `branch` parameter. So it's not clear what's going on. Do you have the same problem if you rename your `branch` to `foo` like you mention here, or `branchName` etc.?

Comment: @ChristopherOrr Yup - independent from parameter name. Also - this present on two Jenkins instances with two different repositories. Anyway, for now, I just use `buildWithParameters?token=blabla` without params - this issues default values from Jenkins, which is more or less suitable for us atm.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this question is old I'll give my answer in case anyone faces this same issue.

I've experienced this exact same issue. After several trials and errors, I've managed to solve it simply by changing the `Content Type` from `x-www-form-urlencoded` to `application/JSON`.

Comment: It might be helpful to add a link to some documentation explaining why for more insight should someone want to dig in further.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the exact same problem with regular webhook jobs (in Jenkins 2.129.) It didn't seem possible to process more than one URL parameter, which, outside of the security token leaves 0 other params.

My way out was to use the '[Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin)' (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48580407/321797).

Not only it helps process as many URL query params as wanted, but more importantly supports the parsing of the HTTP POST body. It is easy with it to extract values of the payload, set them to variables and trigger parameterised downstream jobs with those variables.