# Get payload parameters in Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins, webhooks

I'm a newbie in Jenkins. I followed this [help](https://medium.com/@marc_best/trigger-a-jenkins-build-from-a-github-push-b922468ef1ae) to implement Jenkins, Github and Webhook.

However, I'm stuck in this problem. I want to get the payload parameters in Jenkins to check information such as changes, actions...from payload json.

I wrote some script to test. `ACTION` and `$payload` always returns empty

```
# !/bin/bash    
ACTION=`echo $payload | php -r '$data = file_get_contents("php://stdin"); $json = json_decode($data, true); echo $json["action"];'`
```

I read some tutorials but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few steps that you should follow:

1. Configure a web-hook in GitHub by which you will start communicating with Jenkins. This can be easily by going to your *GitHub repository --> Setting --> Web-hooks*.
2. Make the entry for content-type as `application/x-www-form-encoded`.
3. Select the event as Push event.
4. Create a String parameter in Jenkins Server by the name of `payload`.
5. Following Step 3 GitHub would be able to wrap the content in this variable and send it to Jenkins.
6. In Jenkins you can then read $payload variable when your build is kicked off.
7. Parse the JSON using library of your choice

### **References**

- [How to process a github webhook payload in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407332/how-to-process-a-github-webhook-payload-in-jenkins/31572888)
- https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#payloads

Comment: I enabled the push event on github web hook but I wasn't able to load the payload variable on jenkins. Any idea?

Comment: Doing the above steps and getting a no valid crumb issue -->then you have to disable CSRF Protection for it to work, but there are security issue with this...so be careful

Comment: and how to pass multiple parameters?

Answer (score 3):

Easier way of doing this, without an extra library for parsing JSON, would be using the [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin) in Jenkins.

It can resolve any value from the JSON using JSONPath and assign it to variables available in the build.