# Webhooks how to get BRANCH_NAME to upload it by Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, webhooks, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a case: I want to load a branch with last commit, I mean next, In my bitbucked repo I have many branches, and after developer adds his push commit in [branch-1] webhooks send to Jenkins notificate and updated branch name. So, how my Jenkins bitbucket plugin should gets need branch name from received webhook?

[Jenkins job settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3mZJ.jpg)

[Bitbucket webhooks settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD7ft.jpg)

Comment: You want to read the Branch name when a trigger is occurred ??

Comment: yes, and as result send that branch_name to jenkins variable to make a build with branch_name

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Pipeline to get the details of the branch which is getting triggered
Couple of things you need to keep in mind you will get entire Payload from which you will have to parse the JSON 
[Get payload parameters in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561620/get-payload-parameters-in-jenkins)

After doing the above steps add this to your PipeLine

```
 def object =  new JsonSlurper().parseText("$payload")
    // reading the JSON to see if branch is master or any other
    String refs= new JsonBuilder("$object.ref" ).toPrettyString()
    println "$refs"
    String[] arrBranch =refs.split("/")
    String branch =arrBranch[2]
    println "$branch"
    if (branch=="master")
        echo "deploy to PROD"
    else 
    echo "deploy to staging"
```